Last peer cannot sync on a private Hyperledger Besu free gas network
Based on Hyperledger Besu official Doc I configured a private besu network free gas using IBFT2 with four nodes.
Instead setting it up on a single machine as per documentation, I configured it on three separated remote VMs. Each VM has a unique IP address. Node-1 and Node-2 are on VM-1. Node-3 and Node-4 is on VM-2 and VM-3 respectively.
Each VM is running on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS server. Besu version: besu/v24.7.0/linux-x86_64/openjdk-java-21.
So I started all the four nodes and the network generate blocks and sync! I can interact with it using curl and everything is fine.
To confirm, I run:
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"ibft_getValidatorsByBlockNumber","params":["latest"], "id":1}' localhost:8545

and I got all four validators:
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":["0x5...512058","0x8...247507","0x9...e65bd5","0x9...73329f"]}

However Node-4 is having problem to peer with other nodes and thus sync! I attempted to and have deleted the data directory and restart the node. Just to be sure, I also ping the other VMs and nc to check the firewall are properly configured. So no issue there and VMs can ping and nc with each other.
I even deleted the whole project and redo the setup twice. Each time I reboot the VMs before I start nodes.
Below is some of the WARN messages on Node-4:
2024-08-01 04:51:44.223+00:00 | EthScheduler-Services-5 (downloadHeaders) | WARN  | PipelineChainDownloader | Invalid block detected (BREACH_OF_PROTOCOL). Disconnecting from sync target. Header failed validation: Invalid block 200 (0xe41694178e29eef988a47171680aac83e4320ed61922945f71a25ce238bde092)
2024-08-01 04:51:44.223+00:00 | EthScheduler-Services-5 (downloadHeaders) | WARN  | PipelineChainDownloader | Chain download failed. Restarting after short delay.

I would really appreciate if someone can help. And yes I did read synchronization issues on AWS but I do not use AWS or Digital Ocean. Did I miss anything?
